# When I write python code in terminal it only prints older version of the file (VScode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Just recently got into python and I'm having trouble understanding what's going on.
When I write `print("hello world")`, I input `python3 name.py` in the terminal and it prints.

However when I change the str to (e.g.) `"bye"`, and input the same thing in the terminal, it still prints `hello world`. Why isn't it updating? Thanks

Comment: Did you save the file? VSCode auto-save can be a bit finicky. You can try to manually save the file and then run `python3 name.py` again.

Comment: @YogeshThambidurai Thanks, led me to realize there was an autosave setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you modify the code, you can use **`"ctrl+s"`** to save it.

If you don't save it, run the file directly and it will run the content before the change.